# ios ARC strong and alloc

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a question related to ARC. In my interface I have declared a `uiwebview` as a `strong` property. Inside my code I have lazy loading like so:

```
- (UIWebView *)aWebView{
    if(aWebView == nil){
        aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    }
    return aWebView;
}
```

Is that code ok under ARC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. ARC will include the release call for you.